# Local GET request different from Heroku deployed request

Tags: reactjs, mern

I am trying to deploy my first MERN stack app. I followed the tutorial series linked here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qyomEaXQJFk&t=121s

I am struggling because my entire app breaks to what I believe is a problem with the authorization GET requests.

```
router.get('/user', auth, async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const user = await User.findById(req.user.id).select('-password');
      console.log(user);
      if (!user) throw Error('User does not exist');
      res.json(user);
    } catch (e) {
      res.status(400).json({ msg: e.message });
    }
  });
```

The above is my GET request, fetched at http://localhost:5000/api/auth/user

```
function auth(req, res, next) {
  const token = req.header('x-auth-token');

  if(!token) {res.status(401).json({msg: 'No token, authorization denied'});
  console.log("help");
}

  try {
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, config.get('jwtSecret'));

    req.user = decoded;
    next();
  } catch(e) {
    res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Token is not valid'});
  }
}
```

The above is my middleware that validates the token and allows the GET request to execute.

When I do the request localhost via postman, it returns:

```
{
    "msg": "Token is not valid"
}
```

which is the functionality that I want. However, when my site is deployed at https://pacific-crag-38763.herokuapp.com/ Postman returns

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
    <title>Musify</title>
    <link href="/static/css/main.e195e564.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>...
```

which continues to return my entire index.html document. I have no idea why this is happening, or where it is fetching index.html. My theory is that when I deployed to Heroku, I had to add this to my server.js

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build")))

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/client/build/index.html'));
  });

}
```

So maybe it is somehow sending my index.html from my build folder to my GET request? I am new to all of this so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is struggling with this, I added

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build")))

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/client/build/index.html'));
  });

}
```

Before my

```
app.use('/api/users', require('./routes/api/user'));
app.use('/api/auth', require('./routes/api/auth'));
```

Which caused every GET request to return the build index.html. Moving the if statement below my routes solved the problem.

Spent hours on this.

FML